# Java nio: How to add extension to an absolute path?

Tags: java, path, nio

This feels like it should be something straight forward, but I can seem to find an elegant solution to it without converting to `File`.

Given a `Path`

```
Path path = Paths.get("/a/b/foo")
```

How to do get the path `/a/b/foo.bar`? `subpath` will return a relative path regardless of whether the original path is relative or absolute.

I would prefer not to have to use additional libraries. But, maybe that is the only way?

Comment: string concatenation in argument for Paths.get() would do? Like: path.getPath().toString() + ".bar"

Comment: Yeah, I guess so... convert to a String and then concatentate

Comment: Let me know if it works, I shall add as answer. :)

Comment: you should concat the string.

Comment: Yeah concating the string works. I just worry if there will be any case where `Paths.get(path.toString())` won't give you the original path?

Comment: That won't work if the original `path` is not on the default `FileSystem`. Try `path.resolveSibling(path.getFileName() + ".bar")`.

Comment: @Andreas yes! that works. Please add that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To change the file name of a `Path`, use one of the [`resolveSibling()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolveSibling%28java.nio.file.Path%29) methods:

> This is useful where a file name needs to be *replaced* with another file name.

Using this method ensures that the result `Path` object is for the same [`FileSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) as the source `Path` object.

So, to add extension `".bar"` to a `Path`:

```
path = path.resolveSibling(path.getFileName() + ".bar");
```

Comment: This can *change* an extension, but not add one -- if the Path was `/some/foo` it results in `/some/.bar`.  So I ended up not using a Path at all, just a string.

Comment: @Noumenon You're confused. The code *adds* an extension. It doesn't change it. If `path = Paths.get("/some/foo")`, then `path.getFileName()` is `foo` resulting in the code doing `path = path.resolveSibling("foo.bar")`, which means the code will change `path` to `/some/foo.bar`. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/2cPpQw) for proof.

Comment: By comparing our two REPLs I see my problem was using `.resolveSibling(".bar")` without the file name. Thanks for taking time to explain.